# Finding the shortest path with possibility of ignoring 1(the longest) edge

Tags: graph, path, dijkstra

I was wondering if I can modify Dijkstra’a Alghorithm in this way: 
Let’s say there are 2 paths between two vertices with following lengths:

```
5, 8, 6, 9  // sum=28
2, 4, 8, 25 //sum=39
```

First path is shorter but after ignoring the longest edge in both I get the following sums: 19 and 14, so I choose the second path.

Maybe there is different way to solve it, without using Dijkstra?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko, what's the connection between ur link and question asked by Paulina?

Comment: Why don't you simply update the weights of those edges to 0 and re-run Dijkstra ? The time complexity is the same, so what is the actual problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure is this idea working, but on first it seems to me like it can.

For each visited node, beside distance `D(n)`, store length of longest edge on the path to it, say `L(v)`. Distance of unvisited neighbouring node is `min D(n) + L(n) - max(L(n), weight(v,n))`, for all neighbours `n` that are visited. `L(v)` of next visited node is `max(L(n), weight(v,n))`, if `n` is last node on a path to the `v`. If there are more paths to `v` (more `n's`) with same length, than choose one with largest `L(v)`.